# Golf program passing scores to function

Tags: python

I'm having an issue passing code to a function the "evaluateAndDisplayScore" I've used print function and it shows its passing numbers but not in the "def" order when I use "hole1"

Here is my code

```
class Golf:

 def __init__ (self, hole, score,  par):
     self.hole = hole
     self.score = score
     self.par = par

 def evaluateAndDisplayScore(hole, score, par): #Im having issues here 
     print(hole)
     print(score)
     print(par)
     if score > par:
         results="Over Par"
     elif score < par:
         results="Under Par"
     else:
         results="At Par"
     print(f"You scored {results} on hole # {hole} with a par of {par}.")

score = 0
hole1 = Golf(1, score, 3)
hole2 = Golf(2, score, 4)
hole3 = Golf(3, score, 5)

enterHole = int(input("Enter hole number: "))
score = int(input("Enter score: "))

if enterHole == 1:
   hole1.evaluateAndDisplayScore(enterHole, score)
elif enterHole == 2:
   hole2.evaluateAndDisplayScore(enterHole, score)
elif enterHole == 3:
   hole3.evaluateAndDisplayScore(enterHole, score)
else:
   print("Invalid hole number entered.")
```

---

Here are the examples I'm supposed to match
EXAMPLE RESULTS

Enter the hole number: 1

Enter your score: 5

You scored Over Par on hole # 1 with a par of 3

Enter the hole number: 2

Enter your score: 1

You scored Under Par on hole # 2 with a par of 4

Enter the hole number: 3

Enter your score: 5

You scored At Par on hole # 3 with a par of 5

Comment: What's the purpose of the class fields if you're never using them? Also, first parameter to class methods should always be `self` (not required, but calling it `hole` is confusing when it is actually an instance of the Golf class)

Comment: I'm very new to python what you mean not using the class? I thought I was using it in Golf(1,score,3) also didn't know self needed to be at the start that might be the issue I've been having

Comment: You seem to want `evaluateAndDisplayScore` to accept 3 arguments, but you pass only 2 (where is `par`?). How do you expect this to work? And the first argument of a class method is always implicitly added reference to the class instance.

Comment: My teacher explained Golf(1,score,3) is basically Golf(hole,score,par) which is passed when using hole1.evaluateAndDisplayScore(enterHole,score)

Comment: It is "passed", but you're never using the "passed" values

Comment: Thank you! figure it out after y'all pointed out that I wasn't actually passing the values

Answer (score 1):

First sign you're doing something incorrect is when you try to use numbered variables instead of a list.

Secondly, you're having issues with your method because you're never using the instance variables. See `self.par` in the evaluate function

```
class Golf:

 def __init__ (self, par):
     self.par = par

 def evaluateScore(self, score): 
     par_str = " Par"
     if score > self.par:
         prefix = "Over"
     elif score < self.par:
         prefix = "Under"
     else:
         prefix = "At"
     return prefix + par_str

holes = [
  Golf(3), Golf(4), Golf(5)
]

enterHole = int(input("Enter hole number: "))

if enterHole < 0 or enterHole >= len(holes):
    raise ValueError("Invalid hole number entered.") 

score = int(input("Enter score: "))

hole = holes[enterHole - 1]
result = hole.evaluateScore(score)
print(f"You scored {result} on hole # {enterHole} with a par of {hole.par}.")
```

Comment: O man my teacher wants us to use hole1=Golf(1, score, 3), hole2=Golf(2,score,4), hole3=Golf(3,score,5) is that set up to fail?

Comment: You're welcome to use them, but each instance does not need to have a score or a hole number.

Comment: Thank you for the example above was able to figure it out!